# Have same route respond differently based on HTTP verb

Tags: yii2, routes, yii2-advanced-app

The following is a small snippet of my routes in `_urlManager.php`

```
["pattern" => 'POST /create_chain', 'route' => 'site/add-chain'],
["pattern" => '/create_chain', 'route' => 'site/create-chain']
```

As you can see for POST I want a different action to be called. But this does not work.

For now I've used the following solution on temporary basis:

```
"POST /create_chain" => "site/add-chain",
["pattern" => '/create_chain', 'route' => 'site/create-chain']
```

But I'm not OK with this solution. If anyone knows how I can integrate HTTP VERB in `pattern`, please comment or answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`verb`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-urlrule#$verb-detail) key if you want to configure verb using array syntax:

```
["pattern" => '/create_chain', 'verb' => 'POST', 'route' => 'site/add-chain'],
```